# What happens when bigquery upload job fails after loaded a portion of the JSON file?

Tags: google-bigquery

As the title mentioned, what happens when I start a bigquery upload job and, let's say, after loading 50% of the rows in the JSON file the job failed. Does bigquery rollback everything of the load job or am I left with 50% of the data loaded?

I am appending data daily into a single table and keeping duplicate-free is very important. We are using the HTTP Rest API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery appends data atomically. You will never get half of the data in the table if the load fails. If the job completes successfully, all of the data will show up at once.

There are two additional tricks you can use to prevent duplicates:

1. Specify a job id for the load job. Imagine you pull your network cable mid way through starting the job... how do you know whether it succeeded? Specifying a job id lets you look up the job later if the job creation request fails.
2. Perform your loads to a temporary table, and specify WRITE_TRUNCATE as the writeDisposition. This means that you can run import jobs idempotently to the temporary table, and if you don't know whether a job succeeded, just run another one, and it will overwrite the data. Once you have a load job that completes successfully, run a table copy job with a writeDisposition to WRITE_APPEND to append the new data to your main table.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. So I guess my question is really if the load job in bigquery is "all or nothing"; meaning if a failure will result in no changes in the table at all.

Comment: Yes, a failure will result in no changes to the table.